# Pull extra CRM Data into a Distributed Marketing Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, lightning, dataextensions, help, distributed-marketing

I am building a Distributed Marketing Email that needs to have the senders contact information and ideally a photo. (Phone, Fax, Name, Title, Email, etc.) Is there a clean way to gather that from the CRM rather than having to maintain a separate Data Extension and doing a LOOKUP?

(i.e. I want to add fields to the Distributed Marketing Data Extension for Phone, Fax, Title and other Profile fields from the Agents Profile in the CRM)

Help please...  so close, yet so far away.

Answer (score 0):

We are doing a lookup to the user record on the Salesforce Synchronized data extensions. You'd want to validate that your data extension and field names align, obviously. One of the hidden secrets of looking up to the synchronized DE's is using the Ent. at the beginning of the DE name. That might just be if you have multiple BU's though. Good luck! Distributed Marketing has a lot of documentation needed!

```ampscript
%%[
var @userRows, @sfUserId 
set @sfUserId = sfUserId
set @userRows = LookupRows('Ent.User_Salesforce_1','Id',@sfUserId) 
if RowCount(@userRows) == 1 then 
 var @userRow, @senderTitle, @senderMobile, @senderPhone 
 set @userRow = Row(@userRows,1) 
 set @senderTitle = Field(@userRow, "Title") 
 set @senderPhone = Field(@userRow, "Work_Phone__c") 
 set @senderMobile = Field(@userRow, "Phone") 
endif 

set @sendFromName = [sendFromName] 
set @sendFromEmail = [sendFromEmail] 
]%%
```